# eliminate certain lines of output in shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell

```
SQL>COUNT(*)

34369

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production
```

Above is my output of the query, I need to display the count value in my output screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -n '/COUNT(\*)/{n;n;p}' inputfile
     34369
```

or by `grep` + `tail` combo:

```
grep -A2 'COUNT' inputfile|tail -1
     34369
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, sed actually worked out and got the expected output